# R: comparing each row to the previous one and keeping score

Tags: r, machine-learning, quantitative-finance

I have data.frame that looks like this:

```
> head(df,10)
              DateTime   BP1 BQ1   BP2 BQ2   BP3 BQ3   BP4 BQ4   BP5 BQ5
1  2015-09-16 09:15:01 70730   1     0   0     0   0     0   0     0   0
2  2015-09-16 09:15:01 70735   1 70730   1 70285   1 70185   1     0   0
3  2015-09-16 09:15:01 70905   1 70735   3 70730   1     0   0     0   0
4  2015-09-16 09:15:01 70910   1 70905   1 70735   2 70730   1     0   0
5  2015-09-16 09:15:03 70905   1 70900   1 70730   1 70230   1 70220   1
6  2015-09-16 09:15:06 70910   1 70905   2 70900   1 70795   1 70730   1
7  2015-09-16 09:15:06 70905   2 70900   1 70795   1 70730   1 70220   1
8  2015-09-16 09:15:06 70910   1 70905   2 70900   1 70795   1 70730   1
9  2015-09-16 09:15:07 70915   1 70910   1 70905   1 70900   1 70795   1
10 2015-09-16 09:15:07 71000   1 70915   1 70905   1 70785   1 70730   1
```

BP = BidPrice and BQ = BidQty

My goal is to compare each row to the one before and see if there any modifications/additions/cancellations and based on that give it a score and add them.

Like you can see df[1,2] = df[2,4] so that would account a score of -1 since the price moved down 1 level.

Then, df[4,4] = df[5,2] so that would account to a score of +1 since the price moved up one level.

And so on... 
Do this for every row and then sum the score for that row. So the output should be a vector or a data.frame with positive and negative integers.

What I have so far is very little and I've been racking my brains at this for hours now and haven't gotten anywhere. I think I've ended up with a never ending loop: My code is following:

```
mod<- function(file, level = 5){
  whole_data<- read.csv(file = file,header = FALSE,sep = "", col.names = c("DateTime","Seq","BP1","BQ1","BO1","AP1","AQ1","AO1","BP2","BQ2","BO2","AP2","AQ2","AO2","BP3","BQ3","BO3","AP3","AQ3","AO3","BP4","BQ4","BO4","AP4","AQ4","AO4","BP5","BQ5","BO5","AP5","AQ5","AO5","BP6","BQ6","BO6","AP6","AQ6","AO6","BP7","BQ7","BO7","AP7","AQ7","AO7","BP8","BQ8","BO8","AP8","AQ8","AO8","BP9","BQ9","BO9","AP9","AQ9","AO9","BP10","BQ10","BO10","AP10","AQ10","AO10"), colClasses = c(NA, rep("integer",31), rep("NULL", 30)))
  whole_data<- whole_data[which(whole_data$DateTime != 0),]
  whole_data$DateTime= as.POSIXct(whole_data$DateTime/(10^9), origin="1970-01-01")    #timestamp conversion 
  df<- data.frame(DateTime= whole_data$DateTime, BP1 = whole_data$BP1, BQ1=whole_data$BQ1, BP2 = whole_data$BP2, BQ2=whole_data$BQ2, BP3 = whole_data$BP3, BQ3=whole_data$BQ3, BP4 = whole_data$BP4, BQ4=whole_data$BQ4, BP5 = whole_data$BP5, BQ5=whole_data$BQ5)
  v<- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  for(j in seq_along(c(2,4,6,8,10)))
  if(level == 5){
    x <- df[i+1,j]==df[i,c(2,4,6,8,10)]
    y<- which(x==TRUE)
    v[i]<- c(v,(y-(j-(j-1))*-1))
    i=i+1
  }
  v
}
}
```

For anyone with quant finance background, I am trying to analyse an electronic order book by capturing its order modifications, cancellations and new orders. This is only the first step of many many more than I am trying to do, but any pointers/comments/help I'm sure will go a long way and will be greatly appreciated.

What would be the fastest way to go about this? For loop? I am really lost as to how I should go about this!! Anything that will point me towards the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if any other information is reqd.

Comment: Can you give an example of expected output for the first 5 lines or so?

Comment: I have made the edit. So the end result I need is a lot more than this but from what I have explained in my question so far, the output I need is as shown. I did it by hand, couldn't get it any other way.

Comment: Take a look at  `sign` and `diff` and `lapply` -functions. Those should do the job

Comment: Im sorry guys, the edit with the output required I posted is wrong. I was mistaken, so Im gonna take it off.  I'm currently working on this and will post/edit when I have gotten somewhere. I'm finally making headway.